# Access is Denied when i want to Create Folder inside Content Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am using this code to upload a file with ASP.NET MVC everything is OK but it cant Access to Upload Folder :

```
public static char DirSeparator = System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        public static string FilesPath = "Content" + DirSeparator + "Uploads" + DirSeparator;
        public static string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (null == file) return "";
            if (!(file.ContentLength > 0)) return "";
            string fileName = file.FileName; string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (null == fileExt) return "";
            if (!Directory.Exists(FilesPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(FilesPath);
            }
            string path = FilesPath + DirSeparator + fileName;
            file.SaveAs(Path.GetFullPath(path));
            return fileName;
        }
```

and i get this error :

```
Access to '/Content/Upload/' is Denied
```

where is my problem,
**Thanks in your Advise**

Comment: Are you running your application under IIS 7?

Comment: no,i use on Visual Studio.

Comment: Basically Visual Studio WebDev WebServer (Cassini) is running under your windows credential. So it has to have enough access to write anywhere your windows user can write.
Can you debug and track the code and see which line exactly throw the error. And check if it tries to write/read to/from C:\content\upload. Furthermore, if you're trying to access through I/O file system, it should be '\Content\Upload\' not '/Content/Upload/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with permissions, and that your permission is being run as a user that does not have access to the location where you are requesting it to make a directory. Be sure that your user owns or has group permissions to be in, and create file/folders in the location you are trying.

Comment: thanks,when i create Folder Manually,it's not recognize folder and Directory.CreateDirectory(FilesPath); runs then i get that error that i told.